# Помогите пожалуйста не могу отобразить комменты в Django

Tags: python, django, django-model

Это мой код

```py
class DetailNews(DetailView, CreateView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'app_news/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'detail'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('news')
    form_class = CommentNewsForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailNews, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Детальная страница'
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        comment = Comment.objects.all()
        com_form = CommentNewsForm(request.POST, instance=comment)
        if com_form.is_valid():
            com = com_form.save()
            return redirect('news')
        return render(request, 'app_news/detail.html', context={'form': com_form, 'comment': comment})
```

Это мой HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>{{ detail.title }}</h1>
  <h3>{{ detail.content }}</h3>
  <h5>Дата создания: {{ detail.create_time }}</h5>
  <h5>Дата обновления: {{ detail.time_update }}</h5>
  {{ comment }}

  {% for i in  comment %}
    <h5>Комментарии: {{ i }}</h5>
  {% endfor %}
  <p><h3><a href="{{detail.slug}}/update">Изменить новость</a></h3>

  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}<br>
    <!--{{ form.body }}<br>-->
    <button type="submit">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Не получается отобразить комменты на страничке.

Answer (score 0):

Перш за все не розумію цього:

###### Дата обновления: {{ detail.time_update }}

{{ comment }}
Тут нічого не відобразить оскільки там query set

Друге ваш код буде показувати коменти лише при пост запиті і коми ви вкажете поле яке ви бажаєте бачити, до прикладу {{ i.user }}

```
{% for i in  comment %}<h5>Комментарии: {{ i }}</h5>{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Дата обновления: {{ detail.time_update }} это для другой модели

Comment: {{ comment }} це маю на увазі,